# Cycling through a whole array after button press

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

To summarize my current efforts, I have made a very basic program that, upon a button press, moves to the next section of a traffic light (starts on red, upon press goes to amber etc.), as each image for the traffic light is stored in an array. This does work as intended but I now need to change this code to make it so that upon a button press, rather than just going to the next thing in the array, it cycles through all of them for a certain amount of time, simulating a traffic light. I could not for the life of me find out where to start, and everything I have tried (`setTimeout`, `setInterval`) has not worked as intended.

Here is my code (without any additions/changes):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1 style="font-size:300%">Changing Traffic Lights</h1>
<p> 
<button type="button" onclick="changeLights()">Change Lights</button>
</p>

<img id="light" src="traffic-light-red.jpg">

<script>
var list = [
    "traffic-light-red.jpg",
    "traffic-light-amber.jpg",
    "traffic-light-green.jpg"
];

var index = 0;

function changeLights() {
    index = index + 1;      
    if (index == list.length) 
    index = 0;      
    var image = document.getElementById('light');     
    image.src=list[index];
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
// Array of light images:
var list = [
    "traffic-light-red.jpg",
    "traffic-light-amber.jpg",
    "traffic-light-green.jpg"
];

// Counter to keep track of which image is displayed
var index = 0;

// Get DOM references:
var btnStart = document.getElementById("btnChange");
var image = document.getElementById('light'); 

// Variable to keep track of timer
var timer = null;

// Wire click events for buttons:
btnStart.addEventListener("click", changeLights);

function changeLights() { 
    // Only continue if we haven't cycled through all the 
    // items in the array yet
    if(index < list.length-1){
      
        // Make this function call itself again in approx. 1.5 seconds
        timer = setTimeout(changeLights, 1500);    
    }
    
    // Change the image source and alternate text
    image.src = list[index];
    image.alt = list[index];

    index++;  // Bump up index  
}
```

```html
<h1 style="font-size:300%">Changing Traffic Lights</h1>
<p> 
<button type="button" id=btnChange>Change Lights</button>
</p>
<img id="light" src="traffic-light-red.jpg" alt="traffic-light-red.jpg">
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for, but is there any way to make it so that instead of the button to stop the cycling, it automatically stops after one single turn through the array?